# How to define a formula in vba?

Tags: vba

I want to define a Function of the following expression and Use it like how i use SUM,AVERAGE etc. This formula, as you can see, has only 1 arguement (Cell value of E28) However, if someone can help me for a function with more than 1 argument it will be great !

I'm new to VBA, kindly excuse my flaws,if any.

```
KandhasFormula=IF(AND(E28<250000),0,IF(AND(E28>250000,E28<500000),E28,IF(AND(E28>500000,E28<1000000),12500+0.2*(-500000+E28),112500+0.3*(-1000000+E28))))
```

Comment: Did you do any research? `Google`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? I took the liberty of changing the "<" to "<=", making a guess at what you wanted the value to be when your input exactly equals 250000, 500000, or 1000000.

```
Option Explicit

Function KandhasFormula(rng As Range) As Double

    If rng.Count > 1 Or Not VarType(rng.Value) = vbDouble Then Exit Function

    If rng.Value <= 250000 Then
        KandhasFormula = 0
    ElseIf rng.Value > 250000 And rng.Value <= 500000 Then
        KandhasFormula = rng.Value
    ElseIf rng.Value > 500000 And rng.Value <= 1000000 Then
        KandhasFormula = 12500 + 0.2 * (rng.Value - 500000)
    Else
        KandhasFormula = 112500 + 0.3 * (rng.Value - 1000000)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: thanks @BigBen ! Can you explain me why you are making rng(my input E28 from my expression) as a Range and not a Double ?

Comment: Because `rng` is a `Range` with a `.value` that may or may not be a `Double`.